# Do multiple Archetypes work together?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What if I had three different archetypes on the field: [Archetype of Imagination](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archetype%20of%20Imagination) (gives flying), [Archetype of Endurance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archetype%20of%20Endurance) (gives hexproof), and [Archetype of Finality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archetype%20of%20Finality) (gives deathtouch)? Would all three of their effects work on my creatures at once or not at all because of the Archetype of Endurance?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they'll work together. The definition of hexproof is:

> 702.11b "Hexproof" on a permanent means "This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control."

The Archetypes' abilities don't target, *and* they're not controlled by your opponent, so hexproof definitely does not prevent them from applying.